# 2 tables below one another and image in side

Tags: tables, graphics, positioning, layout

I am trying to create an image and 2 tables one below the other next to it using the below code with `floatrow` package

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox{%
  \rule{3cm}{3cm}%
}{%
  \caption{A figure}%
}
\capbtabbox{%
  \begin{tabular}{cc} \hline
  Author & Title \\ \hline
  Knuth & The \TeX book \\
  Lamport & \LaTeX \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tabular}{cc} \hline
  Author & Title \\ \hline
  Knuth & The \TeX book \\
  Lamport & \LaTeX \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
}{}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}
```

but I could only get this layout

[image]

Could you please let me know if there is an easy fix to place the tables one below the other instead of side by side. Thanks.

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document! If you like to have image and table above each other, insert empty lines between them ...

Comment: Try adding some vertical spacing in between the tables. You may use `\vspace{}`, `\smallskip`, etc.

Comment: Yes, but the first step is to stop using floatrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better I can do:
[image]

with this (no professional)code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}[2007/04/11]

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]\\
    
    \begin{figure}[h!]
    %   \vspace{1cm}
    \rule{3cm}{4cm}%
    \end{figure}
    \vspace{-5.3cm} % <<<< TRIALS AND ERRORS
\qquad \qquad
    \begin{table}[htp]
        \centering
        \caption{First table}
        \begin{tabular}{lll}
            \hline
            1 & 2 & $\sin x$\\
            3 & 4 & $\cos x$\\
            5 & 6 & $\tan x$\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{First table}
        
        \begin{tabular}{lll}
            \hline
            1 & 2 & $\sin x$\\
            3 & 4 & $\cos x$\\
            5 & 6 & $\tan x$\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}\\
    \noindent\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this more complicated than it has to be, but it can handle a variety of widths this way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\hrule% MWE only
\centering
\sbox0{\rule{3cm}{3cm}}% measure width
\begin{minipage}[c]{\wd0}
  \usebox0
  \caption{A figure}%
\end{minipage}\hfil
\sbox1{\begin{tabular}{cc} \hline
  Author & Title \\ \hline
  Knuth & The \TeX book \\
  Lamport & \LaTeX \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}}%
\sbox2{\begin{tabular}{cc} \hline
  Author & Title \\ \hline
  Knuth & The \TeX book \\
  Lamport & \LaTeX \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}}%
\ifdim\wd1>\wd2 \dimen0=wd1 \else \dimen0=\wd2 \fi
\begin{minipage}[c]{\dimen0}
\captionof{table}{A table}
\centering
\usebox1

\usebox2
\end{minipage}
\hrule% MWE only
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```